# Grant sudo based on SELinux

Tags: redhat, selinux

I've recently come across SELinux and `sudo`.
Is it possible to allow users `sudo` when SELinux is permissive, and block these while allowing others when SELinux is enforced?

I've looked at section **3.9. Confining an administrator by using sudo and the sysadm_r role** [RedHat Using SELinux](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us.%20/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html-single/using_selinux/index), and I understand it's possible to give someone with `sysadm_r` sudo acceess. But how do I deny certain users based on SELinux is enforced or permissive?

Answer (score 0):

> The SELinux policy uses these contexts in a series of rules which
> define how processes can interact with each other and the various
> system resources. By default, the policy does not allow any
> interaction unless a rule explicitly grants access.

So you need to look for existing default/added policied and remove it if it allows users to use `sudo`, after that you can add user which you want.

Comment: Like... If I have two users (alice and bob). I want both of them to run sudo then SELinux is set to permissive and only allow alice to run sudo when SELinux is enfored...

Answer (score 0):

Added bob and alice to `staff_u`:

```
# semanage login -l

Login Name           SELinux User         MLS/MCS Range        Service

__default__          unconfined_u         s0-s0:c0.c1023       *
alice                staff_u              s0-s0:c0.c1023       *
bob                  staff_u              s0-s0:c0.c1023       *
```

In the sudoers file added following:

```
alice ALL=(ALL) TYPE=staff_t ROLE=staff_r ALL
bob ALL=(ALL) TYPE=sysadm_t ROLE=sysadm_r ALL
```

Now if SELinux is enforced only `bob` is allowed to run. `alice` is allowed to run when it's permissive:

```
[alice@vm ~]$ getenforce 
Enforcing
[alicevm ~]$ sudo su
[sudo] password for alice: 
su: avc.c:74: avc_context_to_sid_raw: Assertion `avc_running' failed.
Aborted
[alice@vm ~]$ getenforce 
Permissive
[alice@vm ~]$ sudo su
[root@vm alice]#
```